# Why java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean is internally implemented with int?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, atomic, java.util.concurrent

AtomicBoolean stores its value in:

```
private volatile int value;
```

Then, for example, extracting its value is done like this:

```
    public final boolean get() {
    return value != 0;
}
```

What is the reason behind it? Why `boolean` was not used?

Comment: Because at the machine level there are no booleans, only integers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AFAIK, `int` is the smallest type CAS operations can be implemented across different machine types.

Note: as object allocations are 8 byte aligned, using a smaller type wouldn't save any memory.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is to be able to base several of the `Atomic` classes on the same base (`Unsafe`), which uses integer and provides the compare and swap operation.

[Concurrency in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) provides a good explanation of the inner workings.